# Concrete5 5.6.x - Setting Attribute Type Associations programmatically in a package controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, concrete5

I'm setting up a package for Concrete5 **5.6.x** that adds a bunch of User Attributes on install. One of them uses the image/file attribute that comes with Concrete5. When you install Concrete5 it does not add the image/file attribute type to User Attributes by default (see my screenshot below). So when my package goes to add this new attribute it won't install because it's not available there. It doesn't error out, it just does nothing.

In the dashboard I can go in and check boxes to make it available:
[image: Attribute Type Associations in the Dashboard]

It's not realistic to tell people to do that first before installing the package. There must be a way to do it programmatically but I can't find anything in the forums or anywhere.

Here's the code for the controller function as it is now:

```
private function addUsersAttr($pkg){
 Loader::model('user_attributes');    

$img_att = AttributeType::getByHandle('image_file');

// Set to User
    $user_att_coll = AttributeKeyCategory::getByHandle('user'); 
    if (!$user_att_coll->allowAttributeSets()) {
        $user_att_coll->setAllowAttributeSets(AttributeKeyCategory::ASET_ALLOW_SINGLE);
     }

     // User Attribute Set & Attributes
    $user_att_set = AttributeSet::getByHandle('author_info');
    if(!is_object($user_att_set)){
            $user_att_set = $user_att_coll->addSet('author_info', t('Author Info'),$pkg);
    }

$ai_portrait=CollectionAttributeKey::getByHandle('ui_portrait'); 
    if( !is_object($ai_portrait) ) {
        CollectionAttributeKey::add($img_att,
        array('akHandle' => 'ui_portrait',
        'akName' => t('Portrait Image'),
        'akIsSearchable' => false, 
        'uakProfileEdit' => true, 
        'uakProfileEditRequired'=> false, 
        'uakRegisterEdit' => false, 
        'uakProfileEditRequired'=>false,
        'displayOrder'=> '9'
        ), $pkg)->setAttributeSet($user_att_set); 
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you are using CollectionAttributeKey but in your statement you said you are trying to add a User Attribute.  If you want to add a User Attribute you need to use UserAttributeKey.